# JavaScript: expected an identifier and instead saw 'myFunction'

Tags: javascript

i'm new to JavaScript, in this Udemy lame course we programmed a simple clock, I followed instructions but still got an error:

First error, didn't use "use strict" so got an error for that.

Second, tried to use strict but guess didn't do it right. tried to use it at beginning of code on it's own.

the instructor wouldn't answer... and I really want to solve it. tried to look how, but still couldn't.

tried "use strict"; at the beginning on it's own. got "use the function form of "use strict".

tried to set - function ("use strict"); at beginning of code but got "missing name in function statement"

than tried - the example of code here but got "expected an identifier and instead saw 'myFunction'.

thanks so much for help
trying to learn on my own but it's hard.

```
setInterval(function ("myFunction") {

myFunction("use strict");  
var currentTime = new Date();
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
var period = "AM";

 if (hours >= 12) {
        period = "PM";
 }
if (hours > 12) {
        hours = hours - 12;
 }
if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
 }
if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
 }
var clockTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + period;
var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
    clock.innerText = 'clockTime';
}, 1000);
```

got errors that I don't know how to solve, described up.

Comment: `function ("myFunction") {` is invalid syntax.

Comment: `myFunction("use strict");` is not "the function form of use strict" either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
setInterval(myfunction, 1000)

function myfunction(){
'use strict'
//your code here
}
```

or:

```
setInterval(function(){
'use strict'
//your code here
}, 1000)
```

Also, since you are trying to show the time, make the clockTime a variable, not a string.

```
clock.innerText = clockTime;
```

Comment: you're tips were helpful :)